# Содержание текста внутри BLOB-объекта с ограниченным радиусом

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css-selectors

**Проблема**: при использовании `border-radius` с `overflow` - текст в углах пропадает.
**Вопрос:** можно ли разместить текст в пределах `border-radius`?
Я не знаю длины текста для каждой страницы, поэтому решение должно работать для большинства сценариев.

```html
<div style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 16px 10px rgba(130,124,110,.25);border-radius: 39% 28% 64% 20% / 28% 16% 57% 66%;max-width:500px;max-height:500px;overflow:hidden;">
  <ul>
    <li>Chuck Norris doesn’t read books. He stares them down until he gets the information he wants.</li>
    <li>Time waits for no man. Unless that man is Chuck Norris.</li>
    <li>If you spell Chuck Norris in Scrabble, you win. Forever.</li>
    <li>Chuck Norris breathes air … five times a day.</li>
    <li>In the Beginning there was nothing … then Chuck Norris roundhouse kicked nothing and told it to get a job.</li>
    <li>When God said, “Let there be light!” Chuck said, “Say Please.”</li>
    <li>Chuck Norris has a mug of nails instead of coffee in the morning.</li>
    <li>If Chuck Norris were to travel to an alternate dimension in which there was another Chuck Norris and they both fought, they would both win.</li>
    <li>The dinosaurs looked at Chuck Norris the wrong way once. You know what happened to them.</li>
    <li>Chuck Norris’ tears cure cancer. Too bad he has never cried.</li>
    <li>Chuck Norris once roundhouse kicked someone so hard that his foot broke the speed of light</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Containing text within border-radius blob](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62596002/7394871) от участника  [@Aron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389110/aron).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62596002/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Вот приближение **<sup>1</sup>** с использованием `shape-outside`. Это немного сложно, но вам нужно добавить больше размер контейнера, чтобы иметь 4 псевдоэлемента для использования в качестве плавающего элемента, а также иметь `flex container`, чтобы иметь возможность использовать процентную высоту с вашими плавающими элементами.
Значение приблизительно, например в зависимости от вашего случая. Нет конкретного расчета, это простой метод проб и ошибок

**<sup>1</sup>**: не идеальное решение, так как часть текста все еще может выходить за пределы

```css
.box {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.box div {
  height: 100%;
}

.box>div {
  height: 130%;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 16px 10px rgba(130, 124, 110, .25);
  border-radius: 39% 28% 64% 20% / 28% 16% 57% 66%;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  height: 33%;
  width: 40%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
}

.box>div::before {
  content: "";
  float: right;
  height: 16%;
  width: 28%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
}

.box>div>div>ul::before {
  content: "";
  float: right;
  height: 75%;
  width: 53%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
}

.box>div>div::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  height: 78%;
  width: 20%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 500px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Chuck Norris doesn’t read books. He stares them down until he gets the information he wants.</li>
          <li>Time waits for no man. Unless that man is Chuck Norris.</li>
          <li>If you spell Chuck Norris in Scrabble, you win. Forever.</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris breathes air … five times a day.</li>
          <li>In the Beginning there was nothing … then Chuck Norris roundhouse kicked nothing and told it to get a job.</li>
          <li>When God said, “Let there be light!” Chuck said, “Say Please.”</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris has a mug of nails instead of coffee in the morning.</li>
          <li>If Chuck Norris were to travel to an alternate dimension in which there was another Chuck Norris and they both fought, they would both win.</li>
          <li>The dinosaurs looked at Chuck Norris the wrong way once. You know what happened to them.</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris’ tears cure cancer. Too bad he has never cried.</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris once roundhouse kicked someone so hard that his foot broke the speed of light</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

***Добавьте немного цвета к плавающему элементу, чтобы лучше понять загадку:***

```css
.box {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.box div {
  height: 100%;
}

.box>div {
  height: 130%;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 16px 10px rgba(130, 124, 110, .25);
  border-radius: 39% 28% 64% 20% / 28% 16% 57% 66%;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  height: 33%;
  width: 40%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
  background:radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right, red 99%, blue 100%);
}

.box>div::before {
  content: "";
  float: right;
  height: 16%;
  width: 28%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left, green 99%, black 100%);
}

.box>div>div>ul::before {
  content: "";
  float: right;
  height: 75%;
  width: 53%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left, yellow 99%, purple 100%);
}

.box>div>div::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  height: 78%;
  width: 20%;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right, transparent 99%, #fff 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right, orange 99%, lightblue 100%);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 500px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Chuck Norris doesn’t read books. He stares them down until he gets the information he wants.</li>
          <li>Time waits for no man. Unless that man is Chuck Norris.</li>
          <li>If you spell Chuck Norris in Scrabble, you win. Forever.</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris breathes air … five times a day.</li>
          <li>In the Beginning there was nothing … then Chuck Norris roundhouse kicked nothing and told it to get a job.</li>
          <li>When God said, “Let there be light!” Chuck said, “Say Please.”</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris has a mug of nails instead of coffee in the morning.</li>
          <li>If Chuck Norris were to travel to an alternate dimension in which there was another Chuck Norris and they both fought, they would both win.</li>
          <li>The dinosaurs looked at Chuck Norris the wrong way once. You know what happened to them.</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris’ tears cure cancer. Too bad he has never cried.</li>
          <li>Chuck Norris once roundhouse kicked someone so hard that his foot broke the speed of light</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62596649/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>